# Local groups mapped to AD users via groups.conf working - but only with ssh login

Tags: active-directory, samba, pam, groups, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running a Samba Active Directory domain with Ubuntu 18.04 clients.

I used the `/etc/security/group.conf` file to successfully create a mapping for domain users to the "dialout" group. I tested it on a number of machines, and it worked fine...

```
rightmire@testpc:~$ groups
domain users dialout master BUILTIN+users rightmire
```

However, today for no apparent reason - it is no longer mapping the dialout group...

```
rightmire@testpc:~$ groups
domain users master BUILTIN+users rightmire
```

Re-running `pam-auth-update` *does* seem to see the groups.conf...

[image: pam-auth-update]

**I'm not sure how to begin troubleshooting this.** Searching for `group.conf` or `pam-auth-update` in the logs comes up with nothing. I'm not seeing anything pertinent in `syslog` or `auth.log`

===

**FILES:**

```
root@testpc:~# cat /etc/security/group.conf | sed '/^#/d'

*;*;*;Al0000-2400;dialout
```

```
root@testpc:~# cat /usr/share/pam-configs/my_groups
Name: activate /etc/security/group.conf
Default: yes
Priority: 900
Auth-Type: Primary
Auth:
        required                        pam_group.so use_first_pass
```

```
root@testpc:~# DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive pam-auth-update
root@testpc:~# 
(I.e. no error...)
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the problem only appears with `su - user`  or local login (even though the local login is via the domain).

I.e. If I login via ssh as the user, the dialout group appears fine...

```
rightmire@localPC:~$ ssh rightmire@remotePC
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)

(...snip...)

68 packages can be updated.
43 updates are security updates.

rightmire@remotePC:~$ groups
domain users dialout master BUILTIN+users 
rightmire@remotePC:~$
```

But if I `su - rightmire`, it does **not** appear...

```
root@remotePC:~# su - rightmire
rightmire@remotePC:~$ groups
domain users master BUILTIN+users domain admins denied rodc password replication group staff konstrukteure vicongroup h2t rightmire
rightmire@remotePC:~$
```

**UPDATE**

I have looked in the `/etc/pam.d`. The two files which contain a reference to `pam_group.so` are `common-auth` and `login`

```
./common-auth:auth      required                        pam_group.so use_first_pass
./login:auth       optional   pam_group.so
```

However, the majority of the (login pertinent) files (including `su` and `sudo` which DON'T set the group, as well as `sshd` which DOES set the groups) include `common-auth` ...

```
./chfn:@include common-auth
./chsh:@include common-auth
./cron:@include common-auth
./cups:@include common-auth
./gdm-password:@include common-auth
./lightdm:@include common-auth
./login:@include common-auth
./other:@include common-auth
./polkit-1:@include common-auth
./samba:@include common-auth
./slock:@include common-auth
./sshd:@include common-auth
./su:@include common-auth
./sudo:@include common-auth
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Dave I don't think I did. If I did, it was so long ago, I don't remember. Sorry :)